# cache_set syntax issue

Tags: drupal, caching

`cache_set($id, 'cache', serialize($my_data), time() + 360);`

I am setting the cache as above. However it does not set the cache for the specified unix time stamp of 1 day. 

`$id = id of the cache;
$my_data = data to be cached;
'cache' = table where it is stored;
time() + 360  = unix timestamp;`

So finally , the correct syntax should be `cache_set($id,$data,'cache',time()+(24*60*60))` 
But this does not update the cache table. The operation `cache_get($id)` also does not execute.

Comment: One day? That's 6 minutes you asked for.

Comment: my apologies, it should be time() + (60*60*24)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shots in the dark...

If you are using Drupal 5 that should work fine. Things to remember: $id should be a string.

Format For Drupal 6:

cache_set($id, $my_data, 'cache', time() + 360)

- You don't need to serialize this already happens within cache_set()

Comment: BUt when i see the cache table, these values are not stored :(